# Google Tag Manager integration on Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-tag-manager

We are working on the implementation of tag manager plugin into our Phonegap Cordova, Ionic project and we have some problems with it.

Everything is installed as it says in the manual (very simple, automatically), and init function (tagManager.init(success, error, GTM-XXXXXX, 30);) returns success callback.

BUT when we try to call trackPage function (tagManager.trackPage(success, error, "/pagehtml");) it never return any success and we can see any data on the Tag Manager part.

We also checked the outgoing traffic from the phone (both Android and iOS) and we couldn't see any outgoing call for Tag Manager.

Please let me know if you would have some experience in integrating tag manager to Ionic framework.

Thank you in advance!

Daniel

Xcode console:

```
2015-06-11 16:41:44.058 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {

parameters =     {

    "&_crc" = 0;

    "&_u" = ".7nL";

    "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";

    "&a" = 1658139289;

    "&aid" = "dk.ovdal.tagman";

    "&an" = tagman;

    "&av" = "0.0.1";

    "&cid" = "1d7ae9f2-e990-4978-88a9-aaca0e16932d";

    "&ds" = app;

    "&sr" = 320x568;

    "&t" = appview;

    "&tid" = "UA-63678409-1";

    "&ul" = uk;

    "&v" = 1;

    "&z" = 364139720163975878;

    gaiVersion = "3.10";

};

timestamp = "2015-06-11 13:41:44 +0000";
```

}

2015-06-11 16:41:44.067 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {

```
parameters =     {

    "&_crc" = 0;

    "&_u" = ".7nL";

    "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";

    "&a" = 1658139289;

    "&aid" = "dk.ovdal.tagman";

    "&an" = tagman;

    "&av" = "0.0.1";

    "&cid" = "1d7ae9f2-e990-4978-88a9-aaca0e16932d";

    "&ds" = app;

    "&sr" = 320x568;

    "&t" = appview;

    "&tid" = "UA-63679031-1";

    "&ul" = uk;

    "&v" = 1;

    "&z" = 364139720163975879;

    cookieName = "_test";

    gaiVersion = "3.10";

};

timestamp = "2015-06-11 13:41:44 +0000";
```

}

2015-06-11 16:41:45.061 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {

```
parameters =     {

    "&_crc" = 0;

    "&_u" = ".7nL";

    "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";

    "&a" = 1658139291;

    "&aid" = "dk.ovdal.tagman";

    "&an" = tagman;

    "&av" = "0.0.1";

    "&cid" = "1d7ae9f2-e990-4978-88a9-aaca0e16932d";

    "&ds" = app;

    "&sr" = 320x568;

    "&t" = appview;

    "&tid" = "UA-63678409-1";

    "&ul" = uk;

    "&v" = 1;

    "&z" = 364139720163975880;

    gaiVersion = "3.10";

};

timestamp = "2015-06-11 13:41:45 +0000";
```

}

2015-06-11 16:41:45.072 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {

```
parameters =     {

    "&_crc" = 0;

    "&_u" = ".7nL";

    "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";

    "&a" = 1658139291;

    "&aid" = "dk.ovdal.tagman";

    "&an" = tagman;

    "&av" = "0.0.1";

    "&cid" = "1d7ae9f2-e990-4978-88a9-aaca0e16932d";

    "&ds" = app;

    "&sr" = 320x568;

    "&t" = appview;

    "&tid" = "UA-63679031-1";

    "&ul" = uk;

    "&v" = 1;

    "&z" = 364139720163975881;

    cookieName = "_test";

    gaiVersion = "3.10";

};

timestamp = "2015-06-11 13:41:45 +0000";
```

}

2015-06-11 16:42:00.953 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestPostUrl:payload:compression:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:167): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch

2015-06-11 16:42:00.954 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:612): Sending hit(s) POST: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch

2015-06-11 16:42:01.481 tagman[2021:804930] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:208): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200

2015-06-11 16:42:01.483 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:509): hit(s) Successfully deleted

2015-06-11 16:42:01.488 tagman[2021:804989] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:219): 6 hit(s) sent